# I am trying create an insert from html to mysql database with a php script

Tags: php, html, mysql, lamp

i have tried several code scripts i found on inserting into a mysql data base from an html form using php.  I used the following code and all i get is a blank page. the lastest version of the script i tried was from a different question. The code is below. I am using a lamp server on ubuntu.

```
 <?php

define('DB_NAME', 'DBNAME');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'toor');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

if (!$link) {
    dir('There was a problem when trying to connect to the host. Please contact Tech Support. Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$link) {
    dir('There was a problem when trying to connect to the database. Please contact Tech Support. Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

$date = $_POST['date'];
$charge = $_POST['charge'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$client_no = $_POST['client_no'];
$client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
$check_no = $_POST['check_no'];
$check = $_POST['check'];
$cash = $_POST['cash'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$staff_initials = $_POST['staff_initials'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO payments (date, charge, payment, client_no, client_name, check_no, check_amonia, cash, notes, staff_initials) VALUES ('$date', '$charge', '$payment', '$client_no', '$client_name', '$check_no', '$check', '$cash', '$notes', '$staff_initials')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

when i submit the html page and i land on this page it is blank and nothing is sent to the mysql database.

Comment: blank page means errors (via php); check for them and update your post to contain what they are

Comment: as a side note, your script is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: To help see your errors, two places where you have `dir(`, should instead be `die(`.  The 'e' are 'r' are next to each other on the keyboard, so this is likely a typo.  There may be other issues, but I'd start with that first.

Comment: If this is all of your script and assuming that those `dir()` are `die()` and again assuming you have no errors in your data, this piece of code if works without any errors will not output anything and you **SHOULD** see a blank page!!

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Time to ditch the old `mysql_` functions, use `mysqli_` or `pdo` prepared statements  with placeholders .  echo something to the screen if successful.